# Facebook event profile picture from external URL

Tags: php, facebook, events, facebook-events

I am trying create Facebook event with PHP. The last problem which I have is profile picture.

My questions are:
 
Can I use external picture url for event profile picture??
 
If yes, than how??

Comment: This is weird, because in the event creation you can use parameter "picture - The URL of the event's picture"

Comment: Oh... sorry.. I thought you meant that you wanted to host the image externally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code from Lix works just from part. But here is an full working code.

```
$externalImage = 'External link to image';
$tempImagePath = 'Local link to save image';
$user = 123456789; // USER ID
// save image
file_put_contents( $tempImagePath, file_get_contents( $externalImage ));
// Create data for new event
$data = array(
  'name'         => 'Event title',
  'description'  => 'Event description',
  'owner'        => $user, // user as owner of this event
  'location'     => 'Location',
  'start_time'   => '2013-05-08T11:00:00-0700',
  'end_time'     => '2013-05-09T19:00:00-0700',
  '@file.jpg'    => '@'.realpath($tempImagePath),
  'privacy_type' => 'OPEN'
);
// Create event
$eventID = $facebook->api('/'.$account.'/events', 'post', $data);
```

If you have some questions just write me.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to actually use that URL to send as the profile picture, but you will be able to use it if you first download it to your server. A simply combination of `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` can copy over the image.

```
$externalImage = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/';
$tempImagePath = 'tmp/temp_image_path.jpg';
// save remote file to the server to $tempImagePath
file_put_contents( $tempImagePath, file_get_contents( $externalImage ));
// upload the image to the event
$facebook->api("/EVENT_ID/picture", "POST", 
  array('source' => '@'. realpath($tempImagePath) )
);
// remove temp image
unlink($tempImagePath);
```

Comment: It's not working. Error: Array to string conversion in $facebook->api call

Comment: One of the parameters are providing is an array where it should be a string. Take a look at the parameters you have specified...